# How to avoid warning using the javafx-maven-plugin to create executable without installer for Windows?

Tags: windows, javafx, executable

In our project we use the [Maven plugin javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) to create a native executable for our JavaFX application. Our configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>8.8.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <vendor>our company</vendor>
    <mainClass>foo.bar.MainClass</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After running ``mvn jfx:native'' an exeutable EXE file is successfully created. That executable comes without an installer routine as we wanted. However, the building log warns us about not using an installer builder:

```
[INFO] Skipping 'EXE Installer' because of configuration error 'Can not find Inno Setup Compiler (iscc.exe).'
Advice to fix:   Download Inno Setup 5 or later from http://www.jrsoftware.org and add it to the PATH.
[INFO] Skipping 'MSI Installer' because of configuration error 'Can not find WiX tools (light.exe, candle.exe).'
Advice to fix:   Download WiX 3.0 or later from http://wix.sf.net and add it to the PATH.
```

Is there a way to tell the plugin we explicitely do not want an installer routine to be created to avoid these warnings?

These warnings are not a big issue, but we try to keep our project as clean as possible.

**Update 1:** In order to create the executable during the package phase of maven, I added the following configuration (proposed by http://javafx-maven-plugin.github.io):

```
<executions>
  <execution>
  <!-- required before build-native -->
    <id>create-jfxjar</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>build-jar</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
  <execution>
    <id>create-native</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>build-native</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be avoided by directly setting the wanted bundler.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.8.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <vendor>our company</vendor>
        <mainClass>foo.bar.MainClass</mainClass>
        <!-- win.app | linux.app | mac.app | exe | msi | rpm | deb -->
        <bundler>win.app</bundler>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of that project

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you. However, when I use the bundler win.app I get another warning stating '[WARNING] No bundler found for given id win.app. Please check your configuration.'. I also added executions configuration to create the bundler during the package phase of maven. See Update 1.

Comment: Thats really odd, are you sure you have OracleJDK installed on windows? Which version?

Comment: Yes, I use the original JKD from Oracle. I use JDK 1.8 and just installed the latest Update 152. I tried it again and the same warning shows up. As output I get jfx/app/my-program.jar with another subfolder for dependent libraries. However, the executable does not exist. The subfolder javafx/native is missing. I use Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit.

Comment: @FibreFoX I get the same warning "[WARNING] No bundler found for given id win.app. Please check your configuration." and also use oracle jdk 1.8.0_202. (64Bit). Any solution?

Comment: Now I removed the bundle tag again (and thus still get the warnings) however the result is generated in the following folder: `target\jfx\native\myApp`